# Find a non-abelian group $G$ and a positive integer m such that for all $g,h \in G$, $(gh)^m = g^mh^m$and $(gh)^{m+1} = g^{m+1}h^{m+1}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find a non-abelian group $G$ and a positive integer m such that for all $g,h \in G$, $$(gh)^m = g^mh^m$$ and $$(gh)^{m+1} = g^{m+1}h^{m+1}.$$

I can't find an example.

Comment: Try any finite nonabelian group.

Comment: Look for a very small non abelian group (which is the same as @spin's hint…)

Comment: Hint: this always works for $m=0$. But since the question asked for "positive" you need to shift that exponent up to satisfy that requirement, without changing the essence. Bonus: you also get $(gh)^m=h^mg^m$ and $(gh)^{m-1}=h^{m-1}g^{m-1}$.

Comment: $S_3$ doesn't work right?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: such $m$ exists for *any* finite group. Can you tell what $g^{|G|}$ is? And so what about $g^{|G|+1}$?

Comment: $g^{|G|}$ is the identity and $g^{|G|+1}$ is g. so what does this tell me?

Comment: @user136266 Try with $m=|G|$, then.

Comment: $(gh)^{|G|} = g^{|G|}h^{|G|} = 1$ and $(gh)^{|G|+1} = (gh)^{|G|}(gh) = gh = g(gh)^{|G|}h = g^{|G|+1}h^{|G|+1} $. Hence this work for all finite group?

Comment: so $S_3$ works also?

Comment: @user136266 Yes, any finite group (abelian or not).